# ASP.net Token Based Authentication

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, authentication

I have a web application built using ASP.NET MVC 5.

I would like to know **if i were to use a token based authentication as opposed to a session-based authentication(forms authentication)** (using **OWIN** as the authentication middle-ware), do i need to add an additional API Controller layer to my current Controller methods now?

I have a simple controller method that allows me to does a HTTP Post to submit a query to a database and retrieve it back via ajax.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult SearchOrders(SearchModel searchModel)
{
     // retrieve some data
}
```

Comment: depends what else you want to do.  Also keep in mind that going with a Owin plugin like IdentityServer3 will also need consideration of a SSL